# Issue with AJAX in php

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to write very simple AJAX but have some problem with that.
here is my ajax code:

```
<div id="userHeader">
<img src="/images/logout.png" alt="logout"  title="exit"  onclick="ajaxLogOut()" style="cursor: pointer;">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxLogOut(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/user/logout.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
//  location.reload();
}
```

and my logout.php:

```
<?php

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['log_in'])) {
unset($_SESSION['log_in']);
unset($_SESSION['username']);
session_destroy();
}
?>
```

The problem is when I comment location.reload() and reload the page manually it work. but if uncomment that line It refresh the page but I'm still logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:**

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","/user/logout.php",false);//sync mode
```

**Or (Async mode with callbak) - Recommend this:**

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","/user/logout.php",true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        location.reload();
    }
}
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Comment: Try also Async-mode. Good Luck. (do not forget to accept my answer by marking it as `correct` :) thanks)

Comment: Answered too fast, had to wait till stack-overflow let me accept it. :)